# Is there any way of moving letters from a string with a set of numbers in python?

Tags: python

For example if you have a list of letters:
"ABCDEFG"
And in the second input you put a list of numbers:
"1346527"
The output would be:
"ACDFEBG"
Is that possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
s = "ABCDEFG"

t = "1346527"

for x in t:
    print(s[int(x) - 1], end="")
```

Output:

```
ACDFEBG
```